# Yii2 formatter asTime return different time

Tags: yii2

Why Yii2 formatter **asTime** method return different time from **asDateTime** method?

```
Yii::$app->formatter->timeZone = 'Asia/Tehran';
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tehran');

var_dump(date_default_timezone_get()); //'Asia/Tehran'
var_dump(Yii::$app->timeZone); //'Asia/Tehran'
var_dump(Yii::$app->formatter->timeZone); //'Asia/Tehran'

var_dump(Yii::$app->formatter->asDatetime('now')); //'Aug 28, 2017, 3:22:25 PM'
var_dump(Yii::$app->formatter->asTime('now')); //'10:52:25 AM' Why it's different from the top
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 2.0.12 Yii checks if value passed to `asTime()` contains information about time (hours, minutes, or seconds). If not (and `now` does not) it takes `defaultTimeZone` instead of `timeZone` (default is UTC).

If you want time in `asDatetime()` to be the same as `asTime()` you need to set `Yii::$app->formatter->defaultTimeZone = 'Asia/Tehran';` but remember it might impact other code and database records saving.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid time zone conversion for date-only `asDate()` and time-only `asTime()` values.

[private function formatDateTimeValue($value, $format, $type)](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/i18n/Formatter.php#L729)